# Why does Visual Studio look for unresolved project references in /bin/debug/ during Release build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm dealing with a strange, non-ideal project/solution architecture and I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to accomplish what is needed. My situation is as follows:

I'm working on software which is broken into two solutions, which I'll call SolutionOne.sln (which builds under VS 2010) and SolutionTwo.sln (which builds under VS 2013). In SolutionOne, we have the following projects:

> SolutionOne.sln
>
> - A.csproj
> - B.csproj
> - C.csproj (includes reference to B.csproj)

In SolutionTwo, we have several projects which are unique to SolutionTwo, but we're also including the "C" project from SolutionOne -- but **not** project B (because outside of this minimal example, there's actually several more chained references and by the time we included them all, it'd basically be the majority of SolutionOne). I understand that this means that when we open SolutionTwo, the "C" project shows an unresolved reference to the "B" project, since it is not included in our second solution.

However: as long as I build SolutionOne before SolutionTwo, in the Debug configuration, the builds are successful and our app is functional. It appears that at build time, Visual Studio is smart enough to grab the built DLLs for the missing "B" project reference from their locations in the SolutionOne build, as these two solutions share a root directory. However, when I try to build both solutions in their Release configurations, I get the following error:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.CSharp.targets(316,9): error MSB3104: The referenced assembly "[path to project]\bin\debug[ProjectReferenceName].dll" was not found. If this assembly is produced by another one of your projects, please make sure to build that project before building this one.

Note that in that error message, it appears to be probing in the correct bin folder, but it's looking in the /debug subdirectory rather than /release even though both solutions are building with their release configurations.

I understand that this is not ideal use of project/solution relationships, but it's highly unlikely that I can reorganize the way this is designed at this stage. Is there any way I can get the Release builds to properly look for the non-resolved Project Reference DLL in the /bin/release/ directory, as I would expect?

Comment: Pretty sure I run into this issue before, sorry don't remember the details.  IIRC, msbuild has a bug/limitation such that if the solution doesn't contain the project file, then msbuild does something to figure out the project reference and always looks for the debug assembly no matter what the specified build configuration.

Comment: @ChrisO, yeah, that about exactly describes what I'm seeing. I'm just wondering if you're correct in thinking it's a bug (as I'm thinking too, at this point) or if there's any way to configure the behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your C.csproj file.

You may be referencing B.dll by a hard-coded path which explicitly references \bin\debug\

**Edit:** @sphanley: In that case, check B.csproj.  Verify that the release OutputPath is setup correctly.  Something like:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>RELEASE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: The reference is a project reference, not an assembly reference, and has no path specified in the .csproj. That's why this seems so odd to me. I'd think it would either not find it in debug OR release, or find it in both.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Build - Configuration Manager 's Active solution configuration is set to Release and the Build column all has checkmarks on them for each project in the solution.

Comment: Both of these things have been verified - it's definitely building the relevant projects with the correct configurations. It's just building to the /bin/release folder, then looking for the DLLs in /bin/debug.